# Pass value with cookies between asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible pass an value(object type) with cookies between  asp.net mvc3 applications? explain with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided both the MVC applications are from the same domain; yes. When you create the cookie, you should allow it to be accessed by the sub domain. This is not an MVC specific restriction, but a general web restriction.

Your browser will prevent pages from different domains from accessing each other’s cookies.
Alos the browser will prevent you from creating cookies for other domains. For example, your application lives in **domaina.com** and you are trying to create a cookie **domainb.com** will not work.

There are hacks and mods around these restrictions but they are generally not recommended.

I recommend you use a plugin/library such as https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to get the task done. There are many examples on how to use the plugin at the above url.

Cheers